# SQL Procedure that Shows Customer Names with the New Balance in a Deposit Table

Tags: sql, oracle, cursor, procedure

I have this code which is meant to get the balance from a certain branch and add interest only to those balances in that branch, then it needs to show only the new balance with the name of the customers who made the deposit for that certain branch

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CustomerNameIntrest (TheBranchName VARCHAR,IntrestRate DEC)
AS
  CURSOR CustomerBalancrDepositRows IS
    SELECT CustomerName FROM Deposit;
  ACustomerName Deposit.CustomerName%TYPE;
BEGIN
  UPDATE Deposit
    SET Balance = Balance + Balance * IntrestRate/100
    WHERE TheBranchName = BranchName;

  OPEN CustomerBalancrDepositRows;

  LOOP
    FETCH CustomerBalancrDepositRows INTO ACustomerName;
    EXIT WHEN CustomerBalancrDepositRows%NOTFOUND;

    dbms_output.put_line(‘Customer Name =’|| ACustomerName);
   END LOOP;
  CLOSE CustomerBalancrDepositRows;
END;
/
```

This code works but it shows the whole table with the new balances. I only want the new balances and the customer names who made the deposit.

Comment: It looks like you need to change the cursor to only fetch rows for the branch name passed in, similar to how the UPDATE statement is written. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [Returning Clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/returninginto_clause.htm#LNPLS01354). You will get all the rows from deposit table, which were affected by the update statement.
Your procedure should look like bellow procedure.

```
create or replace procedure CustomerNameIntrest(TheBranchName varchar,
                                                IntrestRate dec) as
   type T_Deposit_CstName_Type is table of Deposit.Customername%type;
   T_CstName T_Deposit_CstName_Type;
begin
   update Deposit
      set Balance = Balance + Balance * IntrestRate / 100
    where TheBranchName = BranchName
   returning CustomerName bulk collect into T_CstName;
   for i in 1 .. T_CstName.count loop
      dbms_output.put_line('Customer name = ' || T_CstName(i));
   end loop;
end;
```

Hope this will help You.